# Set background color for excel range using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to open an existing .xls file, set the background color for the header and also merge few columns of the 1st row using javascript.

Thanks for any help.

---

Here is my code as of now.. I could, set the background color index of the cell and merge the cells.

```
var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xls.visible = true;
xls.DisplayAlerts=false;
var wb=xls.Workbooks.Open("C:\\ECN REPORT.xls");
xls.Range("A1","B1").Interior.ColorIndex=37;
xls.Range("C1","D1").Interior.ColorIndex=37;
xls.Range("A1:D1").Merge();
wb.SaveAs("C:\\ECN REPORT.xls");
xls.Quit();
```

I have set the DisplayAlerts=False and want to save the excel again with wb.SaveAs(); It saves the file without prompt, but the merge changes are not reflected in the excel file.

Could somebody let me know where im wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem, what have you tried? Could you show the specific piece of code that's not working?

Comment: var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xls.visible = true;
xls.Workbook.Open("C:\\test.xls");
xls.ActiveSheet.Activate;
xls.ActiveSheet.Cells("A1:F6").Interior.ColorIndex=5;
xls.Save();
xls.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font Color:

```
oSheet.Range("A1","X1").Font.ColorIndex = 49;
```

Interior Color:

```
oSheet.Range("A1","X1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15;
```

Merging Cells:

```
oSheet.Range("A1","X1").Merge();
```

or

```
oSheet.Range("A1","X1").MergeCells = true;
```

Comment: well, it puts backgroung color. not able to save and close the excel. It asks for saving the excel each time.

Comment: Merged cells A1:F1 with xls.Range("A1:A6").Merge(); but couldnt put the text in the centre of the merge cells. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the working example for my question.
It checks if the file exists, if so deletes and then creates an excel, merges columns, sets background colors,borders,fon.

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var checkFile= fso.FileExists("C:\\Report.xlsx");
if(checkFile)
{
fso.DeleteFile("C:\\Report.xlsx",true);
}
var ExcelSheet=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","G1").Merge();
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value="ECN REPORT";
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Font.Bold = true;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Font.Size = 24;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","F1").Interior.ColorIndex=2;
// xlEdgeLeft,xlEdgeTop,xlEdgeBottom,xlEdgeRight all set to continuous  borders
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","F1").Borders(7).LineStyle=1;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","F1").Borders(8).LineStyle=1;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","F1").Borders(9).LineStyle=1;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","F1").Borders(10).LineStyle=1;
```